# Who will reach first?

Tags: mazes

Source: [GPUZZLES](http://gpuzzles.com/mind-teasers/4-tank/?source=stack&type=stackpuzzle)

Who will reach first?

[image: Can you solve this]

Comment: Start at the station and work backwards. Takes about 2 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last one is the answer as you can seen in the picture attached.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else answered it yet, it's...

> the train on the bottom. Someone has to do it.

Comment: give more details ?

Comment: The other two lead to an end that does not reach the true end. The bottom one is the only one to make it to said train station. :)